# Don't understand this Python syntax

Tags: python, syntax

Looking through a codebase, I came across this line:

```
assert uri.startswith(node_uri_scheme) and '@' in uri and ':' in uri, uri
```

what is the `, uri` at the end?!

Comment: That's the error message to show if the assertion fails - see https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement

Comment: Ahh I see! I should have been looking at the assert command

Comment: That would certainly have been the logical place to start!

Comment: Been a while since I used python syntax so the thought didn't even enter my mind